# Interesting CSS behaviour re: color inherit and currentColor

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<a id=link1><span>Link 1</span></a>
<a id=link2><span>Link 2</span></a>
```

And the following CSS:

```
a { color: white; }
a:hover { color: green; }
#link1 span { color: white; }
#link2 span { color: inherit; }
a:hover span { color: currentColor; }
```

What's interesting is that, on hover, the `span` in link 1 will stay white, because it has `color: white` explicitly set, whereas the `span` in link 2 will go green, as though `color: inherit` is insufficient to deliver a 'current colour'.

In other words, `currentColor` does not seem to pick up colours specified by `inherit`. This happens even if I change the penultimate line to the more specific

```
#link2 span, #link2:hover span { color: inherit; }
```

Question: Is this intended behaviour, or could it be considered a bug? Confirmed in Firefox and Chrome.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qwtyae8)

```css
* { font-family: 'trebuchet ms'; }
code { color: #c00; font-family: 'courier new'; font-size: .95em; }
a { display: block; color: white; background: black; padding: 1rem; margin: 1rem; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; }
a:hover { color: green; }
#link1 span { color: white; }
#link2 span { color: inherit; }
a:hover span { color: currentColor; }
```

```html
<p>On hover to link 1, the <code>span</code> inside stays white because it has <code>color: white</code> explicitly set, and this is picked up as its <code>currentColor</code></p>
<a id=link1><span>link 1 (I stay white)</span></a>
<p>The <code>span</code> inside link 2, however, has <code>color: inherit</code> set, inheriting the parent <code>a</code>'s <code>color: white</code> definition. This, it seems, is insufficient for white to be picked up as its <code>currentColor</code> on hover to the <code>a</code>, and so it goes green due to the rule <code>a:hover { color: green; }</code>.</p>
<a id=link2><span>link 2 (I go green)</span></a>
```

Comment: `If currentColor is used as the value of the color property, it instead takes its value from the inherited value of the color property.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value

Answer (score 2):

> If currentColor is used as the value of the color property, it instead
>   takes its value from the inherited value of the color property. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword)

On one hand we have the above fact, but here we have CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) at play:

`#link1 span` and `#link2 span` has more *specificity* than `a:hover span` - so the values specified in this CSS rule will take precedence.

This will *inherit* the parent's *green* color:

```
#link2 span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

> Inheritance is always from the parent element in the document tree,
>   even when the parent element is not the containing block. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

And this will set *white* color:

```
#link1 span {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Well done noting the specificity. I thought that was understood but now I think that may be where the confusion could easily arise.

Answer (score 0):

This is as-designed, and you can tell by swapping out `inherit` for `currentColor`. The [spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#currentcolor):

> currentColor: The value of the ‘color’ property. The used value of the ‘currentColor’ keyword is the computed value of the ‘color’ property. **If the ‘currentColor’ keyword is set on the ‘color’ property itself, it is treated as ‘color: inherit’.**

There's a special case for the `color` property, which you've run into. So it correctly gets `green` from the computed property and keeps it.

```css
body { background: black; }
a { display: block; color: white; padding: 1rem; margin: 1rem; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; }
a:hover { color: green; }
#link1 span { color: white; }
#link2 span { color: inherit; }
a:hover span { color: currentColor; }
#link2:hover span { color: currentColor; }
#link3:hover span { color: inherit; }
```

```html
<a id="link1"><span>link 1 (I stay white)</span></a>
<a id="link2"><span>link 2 (I go green w/ currentColor)</span></a>
<a id="link3"><span>link 3 (I go green w/ inherit)</span></a>
```